# Alternative proofs for the divergence of sum of reciprocal of primes

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, alternative-proof, divergent-series, big-list

Many people would know that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_n}$$
where $p_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ prime number, diverges. While reading Tom Apostol's Introduction to analytic number theory, I found a short proof (due to Clarkson) that the series diverges. Here it is:

> We assume the series converges and obtain a contradiction. If the series converges there is an integer $k$ such that
> $$\sum_{m=k+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_m}<\frac{1}{2}$$
> Let $Q = p_1...p_k$ , and consider the numbers $1 + nQ$ for $n = 1, 2, . ..$ None
> of these is divisible by any of the primes $p_1 , ... , p_k$ . Therefore, all the prime
> factors of $l ± nQ$ occur among the primes $p_{k+1}, p_{k+ 2}, . . .$ Therefore for each
> $r \geq 1$ we have
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{r}\frac{1}{1+nQ}\leq\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{m=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_m}\right)^t$$
> since the sum on the right includes among its terms all the terms on the left.
> But the right-hand side of this inequality is dominated by the convergent
> geometric series
> $$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^t$$
> Therefore the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}1/(1+nQ)$ has bounded partial sums and hence
> converges. But this is a contradiction because the integral test or the limit
> comparison test shows that this series diverges.

As I mentioned in my infinitude of primes question, I mentioned that I am not content with only one proof. So please give more proofs of the divergence of the sum of reciprocals. I am not the type of person who thinks that long proof are not elegant; whether short or long, I like every proof. If the proof is too long for this site, please link an article containing the proof.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) article might help.

Comment: I am not sure whether the mentioned proof is valid.

Comment: @Peter I got it from a reputed source (which I don't remember).

Comment: @Peter, if you're refering to the proof attributed to Clarkson, the blockquoted excerpt here is verbatim from page 19 of Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*. (I'm puzzled at the OP's comment about not remembering the source, since they were pretty explicit about where it came from!) The proof seems perfectly valid to me; what in it do you have doubts about?